# Frosting/Icing Twisted Text Blender

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, bezier-curves, geometry

I looked up several ways to write a text in this frosting/icing pattern but couldn't find any.

[image]

I created a curve path in the text I wanted.

[image]

Then made a circle mesh object in this star shape. Added Subsurf. Converted the Circle to a curve.

Then chose the bevel object for the text as this Circle.

This is what I got

[image]

But I cannot find a way to twist the frosting around itself. Notice in the 'Soft' image how the frosting twists around itself. In the text I rendered, it just flows straight

[image]

I also tried Simple Deform Twist modifier, but id did not help.

Also created an elongated cylinder, twisted it and then added the curve modifier but it just squashed it on to the curve.

Comment: Try starting with your 2D strand shape (in your case a star by the looks of it) then apply three modifiers - screw modifier to give you that twisted shape, you can give it as many steps and iterations as you need (2) subsurf to give it geometry and able to bend and (3) curve to follow your text curve.